# DNS resolution not working after avahi installation

Tags: networking, arch-linux, dns, avahi, systemd-resolved

I installed and set up avahi and nss-mdns according to Arch wiki (I'm on Arch) and disabled systemd-resolved's multicast dns, but now dns resolution fails on my machine entirely. I then tried disabling avahi, uninstalling nss-mdns, and reenabling the systemd-networkd multicast DNS, but it still doesn't work. How can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

`mdns_minimal` was missing from `/etc/nsswitch.conf`